# Kadira/mup.js Error: Cannot find module 'fbjs/lib/invariant'

Tags: javascript, meteor

$ npm -v
3.10.3

$ node -v
v4.5.0

I tried to setup mup.js from kadirahq/mup but after

cd .deploy

mup setup

I don't get any status of whether it setup properly or not, just returns next line as opposed to mupx setup which did provide SUCCESS MUPX setup messages along the way.

Can anyone provide actual real example of a working mup.js that is deployed to their own self hosting (no digital ocean examples etc) please as I already did that.

a working mup.js that has real mongo_url, mongo_oplog, root_url because I have tried but none successful yet.

EDIT:

Mac OSX
Meteor 1.4.1.1

Added example of mysparkapp/.deploy/mup.js:

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: 'IP address',
      username: 'root',
      password: 'xxxxxx!'
      //pem: "/Users/seb/.ssh/id_rsa"
      // or leave blank for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
  },

  meteor: {

    name: 'myappdemo',
    //path: '..',
    path: '/Users/seb/myappdemo/',

    docker: {
    image: 'abernix/meteord:base'
    },

    servers: {
      one: {}
    },
    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true
    },
    env: {
      PORT: 63830,
      ROOT_URL: 'http://localhost:63830',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor'
    },

    //dockerImage: 'kadirahq/meteord'
    dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base',
    deployCheckWaitTime: 60
  },

  mongo: {
    oplog: true,
    port: 27017,
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },
  },
};
```

then

$ mup setup

```
Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[138.68.141.215] - setup docker
[138.68.141.215] - setup docker: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Meteor
[138.68.141.215] - Setup Environment

Started TaskList: Setup Mongo
[138.68.141.215] - setup environment
[138.68.141.215] - setup environment: SUCCESS
[138.68.141.215] - copying mongodb.conf
[138.68.141.215] - copying mongodb.conf: SUCCESS
[138.68.141.215] - Setup Environment: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Start Mongo
[138.68.141.215] - start mongo
[138.68.141.215] - start mongo: SUCCESS
```

$ mup deploy

```
Building App Bundle Locally

Started TaskList: Pushing Meteor
[138.68.141.215] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to The Server
[138.68.141.215] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to The Server: SUCCESS
[138.68.141.215] - Pushing the Startup Script
[138.68.141.215] - Pushing the Startup Script: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Configuring  Meteor Environment Variables
[138.68.141.215] - Sending Environment Variables
[138.68.141.215] - Sending Environment Variables: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Start Meteor
[138.68.141.215] - Start Meteor
[138.68.141.215] - Start Meteor: SUCCESS
[138.68.141.215] - Verifying Deployment
[138.68.141.215] x Verifying Deployment: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    : "1.2.8"
    }
    npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No license field.
    => Starting meteor app on port:80
    /bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                            throw(ex);
                            ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'fbjs/lib/invariant'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/react/lib/PooledClass.js:16:17)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Module.Mp.load (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/reify/node/runtime.js:16:23)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

    => Redeploying previous version of the app

    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

    To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=50'

    -----------
```

Then

$ npm install invariant warning --save

```
x Verifying Deployment: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR---------------------------- -------
erm"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install: `node npm-rebuild.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install script 'node npm-rebuild.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the meteor-dev-bundle package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node npm-rebuild.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs meteor-dev-bundle
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls meteor-dev-bundle
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm-debug.log

=> Redeploying previous version of the app

-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=50'

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But later  Error: Cannot find module 'fbjs/lib/invariant' reappears again???

SOLUTION (for me anyway)

```
$npm install -g bcrypt-nodejs && 
$npm uninstall -g bcrypt
```

Comment: I've been having this trouble too in the past few days. It seems to be in connection for me with adding react-router-ssr. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: I finally solved (for my case anyway) npm install -g bcrypt-nodejs and npm uninstall -g bcrypt.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That didn't solve my particular issue but if others have a similar issue feel free to check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476197/meteor-mup-error-fbjs-invariant

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use a full path to your apps location - /users//.. mup.js doesn't like ~/

Otherwise post an example of your mup.js and I'll let you know where you are going wrong.

Comment: Hi @led just added example of mup.js thanks in advance. You mentioned mup.js doesn't like relative path, so does it also mean path: '..' won't work too?

Comment: I just defined my paths from my root on a mac that's something like `/Users/me/development/meteorapp`